# Copy Table Failing with ERROR 000732 in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, table, error-000732, copy

Very new to Python. I am trying to copy between Feature Datasets, Feature Classes, and Tables between two GDBs. Here's my code:

The following attempt works when `Irfan_FC` is a feature class:

```
#Copy Feature Class [Works]  
gp.CopyFeatures_management(r"C:\path\_FGB.gdb\Irfan_FC", r"C:\path\OUTPUT\db_output.gdb\Irfan_FC")
```

The attempt fails when `IrfanTable1` is a table:

```
#Copy Table [Fails] 
gp.CopyFeatures_management(r"C:\path\Irfan_Simple_Input_TBL.gdb\IrfanTable1", r"C:\path\OUTPUT\db_output.gdb\IrfanTable1"

ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset C:\AGOL_Backup\Data\Irfan_Simple_Input_TBL.gdb\IrfanTable1 does not exist or is not supported
```

Eventually, this code will copy from a flat GDB (no datasets) into a target GDB which will have datasets but right now I will be happy to copy just tables.

Comment: Looks like you have a number of attempts above. Please [edit] to be sure you're including only the exact code that's failing and the exact corresponding error message. Also let us know if `IrfanTable1` is a table, a feature class, or something else.

Comment: I have the working lines commented out, as you can see. That was just to show that the paths are correct but copying 'IrfanTable1', which is a Table is failing but copying Feature Class is working.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with my code was that I was using the '`CopyFeatures_management`' function, which seems to expect a 'Feature Class' but I was trying to copy a static table. The code below copies static tables and is working for me.

```
  gp.CopyRows_management(r"C:\path\Irfan_Simple_Input_TBL.gdb\IrfanTable1", r"C:\path\OUTPUT\db_output.gdb\IrfanTable1")
```